# How to handle exception using JOptionPane class

Tags: java, joptionpane

So, I need help with this code. This code will make the user input a double value like double radius. and calculate the area and perimeter of the circle. But I need to check if the radius is correct or not like, if the radius is negative or not and if the user enters a char or a string with it. so if the user enters 34.5gd the code should output "Invalid entry, please try again" and use a loop to input the value again.

I can get the negative part and using JOptionPane I am to get a dialogue box saying "Invalid entry, please try again", but I am unable to check the input for a char or string.

This code is for the driver class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class CircleValidationApp1
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String line;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the radius");
        Circle obj = new Circle();
        NegativeDoubleException obj1 = new  NegativeDoubleException();
        line = input.next();
        obj1.Checkradius(line);
        if(obj1.Checkradius(line)==true)
        {
            System.out.println("valid input");
        }
        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error, Please try again");
            line = input.next();
        }
        input.close();
    }

}
```

This class should handle the input and throw the exception.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class NegativeDoubleException 
{
Double radius;
String line;
Boolean flag = radius instanceof Double;
Circle obj = new Circle();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public void getvalue(String r){
    r=this.line;
    }

public void setvalue(String r){
    getvalue(r);
    }
public Boolean Checkradius(String r){   
    Boolean flag = false;
    try 
        {
            radius = Double.parseDouble(line);
            flag = true;
        }catch( NumberFormatException e)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
    return flag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy you will surround the code that wants from the user to enter a number
with try...catch statement
like this

```
try{
//the code that wants from the user to enter the radius
}catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid entry, please try again");
}
```

and when any Exception happens it will give the invalid entry message and you can close the message and write a new raduis without crashing the program

Comment: I tried this but I think my logic is not correct. would you be able to help with what do I put I the try block.

Answer (score 1):

**first problem :** you must make variable line double not String and in the setters and getters methods of radius you make the setter double and it must be void 
and the getter must be double and in the getter you will write`return radius`
and you will do the following changes

```
public class Circle2 {
double radius;
double area ;
double perimeter;

public  void setradius(double r)
{
this.radius=r;

}
public double getradius(){
return radius;
} 


public void perimeter()
{

System.out.println(2*3.14*radius);
}
public void area(){

area = Math.PI*radius*radius;
System.out.println(area);

}   
}
```

note : I use the pi method in the math class to get more accurate results`Math.PI`

**second :** I make some changes on your main class

```
    public class mainc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double l;
    Circle2 obj = new Circle2();
    Scanner s;

    s = new Scanner(System.in);

    l = s.nextDouble();

    obj.setradius(l);
    obj.perimeter();
    obj.area();
```

**to make anexception if someone didnot enter a number** you will surround all the code in the main by try and catch 
you will do that

```
public class mainc {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double l;
    Circle2 obj = new Circle2();
    Scanner s;

   try{ 
    s = new Scanner(System.in);

    l = s.nextDouble();

    obj.setradius(l);
    obj.perimeter();
    obj.area();
   }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println(e);
       System.out.println("enter a number");
       s = new Scanner(System.in);
       l = s.nextDouble();
    }

   }

   }
```

we added the s = new Scanner(System.in); and the l = s.nextDouble(); again  because if an exception happened it will continue doing there work and dont close

Comment: it is better to use  JOptionPane instead of Scanner to get the radius from the user and you can write exception with try ... catch statement easily and show the invalid entery message

Comment: There is no "builtin Java class" called `Circle`.  There is a JavaFX class called `Circle`, but JavaFX is separate from Java, from Java 11 on: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates.  Furthermore, even if the OP is using an earlier version of Java, there is no risk of collisions *unless* he or she is importing JavaFX classes or packages.  In short, calling this class `Circle` is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: But when I try to call the methods in his circle class it give me another methods and I dont use javafx or importing it olin the program

Comment: I am using java 8

Comment: Then something else is going on Mody.  You can check the Java SE 8 javadocs.  There is no `Circle` builtin class.  Trust me.  I have been programming in Java for 20+ years.

Comment: Yes i am sorry you are right i by mistake import javafx circle class so i didnot find his methods thanks btw i have been programming java for 2 years